# What's wrong with my Java code? It should count the spaces, but returns 0

Tags: java, methods, for-loop

The code is copied below. It should return the number of spaces if the character variable l is equal to a space, but always returns a 0.

I've tested it with letters and it worked, for example if I'm asking it to increment when the variable l is equal to e and enter a sentence with e in, it will count it. But for some reason, not spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class countspace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);         
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence:");            
        String str = input.next();          
        System.out.println(wc(str));

    }

    public static int wc(String sentence) {

        int c = 0;          
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {           
            char l = sentence.charAt(i);                
            if (l == ' ') {                 
                c++;                    
            }               
        }           
        return c;           
    }       
}
```

Comment: just as an aside, you can use sentence.toCharArray() to convert the string into an char[] rather than getting the individual characters like you have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nextLine` instead.  You can also print the line for debugging:

```
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks to this and the other comment from Jon Skeet, I get this now and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[`Scanner.next()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) (with the default delimited) is only parsing as far as the first space - so `str` is only the first word of the sentence.

From the docs for `Scanner`:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Use String `str = input.nextLine()`; instead of String `str = input.next();`
This is the way you should do to get the next string.
You could have checked that str has the wrong value.